# Rails - Append content to helper method's block without <%= %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, rendering

I'm trying to create a helper method that appends stuff and shows the block inside of it, like this:

```
def test &block 
   %{<div> 
      <div> Example content </div>
       <p> #{capture(&block)} </div>
     </div>}.html_safe()
end
```

when I call it like this

```
<%= test do %>
 **stuff
<% end %>
```

it works properly, but when I also need to call it from the controller using ERB.new(), and when I do so, I get an error:

the call:

```
@result = ERB.new(
%{<%= view_context.test do  %>
    <div>content to show inside</div>
  <% end %>}
).result(binding)
```

the error:

```
SyntaxError ((erb):2: syntax error, unexpected ')'
ncat(( view_context.test do  ).to_s); _erbout.concat "\n
```

so I need to call without the "*=*", <% test do ... %>, but when I call it like this, the appended content isn't shown

what am I missing?

Comment: AFAIK Rails uses Erubis, not ERB. They don't quite support the same syntax.

Comment: Tried Erubis::Eruby.new() from the erubis gem but got the same error, is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `content_tag` in your helper would be a better way to do this.

For your error, it may be because you are doing the whole `ERB.new(...)` in your view, should be in an helper.

Comment: i'm doing the ERB.new stuff on my controller; using the content_tag I achieve the same result..

Comment: There it can't work, your `test` method is in an helper so it would need to be defined in your controller (not that it's a good solution).

Comment: It work actually, if I call it without the =, it works and runs the code, the problem is the sintax error when I use <%= and/or the appended content not being shown when called with <% (in this case only the block content is shown)